# Change icon to minus sign when plus icon is clicked

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to modify the code of Bootstrap Sidebar:

http://jsfiddle.net/samtux/8djegrp6/35/

```
<button type="button" class="btn-lg btn btn-default" data-toggle="sidebar" data-target=".sidebar-right">
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span>
</button>
```

I want to turn the plus icon into a minus icon when the toggle is active.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking?

Comment: Remember that warning you got when you tried to post a link to jsFiddle without any code in your question? Yeah, that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DEMO:

**http://jsfiddle.net/8djegrp6/37/**

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="sidebar"]').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('active')
  });
});
```

**CSS:**

```
[data-toggle=sidebar].btn.active span:before {
   content: "\e082"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i did a css adjustment over to your button. is this what you are trying to achieve?

```
.sidebar-menu {
  position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 25px;
}
```

Here's my rendition over to your codes.
http://jsfiddle.net/imarkdesigns/8djegrp6/36/